# creating a line to represent a temp value being using in col = temp on a graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

sorry i'm not sure what the question should be called.

I have a plot of depth against time: depth is coloured by 'Temperature'

```
ggplot(Mn, aes(x = Date_time, y = 1-Depth, col = Temperature)) + 
  geom_line( size = 0) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = 'none') +
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Depth")
```

I want to add a line to the plot representing a certain 'mixed layer' temperature calculated daily, I have a df 'MLD' with date 'Date' format "YYYY-MM-DD" and corresponding number 'MLD_Temp'.

I'm unsure as to how to create this, given the plot uses depth not temperature on the y axis. [image: this is an example]
You can see the red line represents the MLD_Temp value plotted on the depth axis.

Sample data from Mn:

```
"Date_time","Depth","Temperature"
2013-10-14 12:30:00,64.4476273148148,27.549999
2013-10-14 12:30:05,65.9476334145628,27.5
2013-10-14 12:30:10,65.9476395143109,27.400002
2013-10-14 12:30:15,66.4476456140589,27.35
```

Sample data from MLD:

```
"Date","Median10mTemp","MLD_Temp"
2013-10-14,28.900002,28.700002
2013-10-15,29.150002,28.950002
2013-10-16,29.200001,29.000001
2013-10-17,29.1,28.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I didn't see your data but you may try

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = Mn, aes(x = Date_time, y = 1-Depth, col = Temperature), size = 0) + 
  geom_line(data = MLD,aes(x = Date, y = MLD_Temp), color = "red") + #color = red after first bracket or error
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = 'none') +
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Depth")
```

Comment: I get the following error:
```
Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
`mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2::geom_line(...)
 2. ggplot2::layer(...)
 3. ggplot2:::validate_mapping(mapping)
```

Comment: @Rstudent I edit my code. Would you try that again?

Comment: same error unfortunately. i have added samples above
hmm you left a ) after Temperature, trying again

Comment: @Rstudent I add some more argument and please be sure to confirm that `Date` and`Date_time`'s type are sort of time format(i.e. `as.Date` , `as.POSIXCT`, etc)

Comment: ok, making progress. 
"Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only". ```Date_time``` is POSIXct and ```Date``` is as.Date.

Comment: I ran a crude ```MLD$Date <- as.POSIXct.Date(MLD$Date)``` which converts each 'Date' to POSIXct with 8am (unsure why 8am), but keeps individual dates.
now i get ```Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale```